# Questions about vocabulary related to publishing and writing - proper words

Tags: word-choice, phrases, vocabulary

Updating my resume and converting it to English, I encountered the following issues:

1. I have written a few technical books. In the resume summary, what should I refer to myself as? Writer, author..? I would like to emphasize the subject (technical stuff), would "technical writer" be correctly understood? In my mother language, we distinct between those who contribute to magazines and those who author books. Of course I want the resume to be as clear as possible.
2. The books I wrote were published (printed) by a publisher. Of course I would like to show that these were not "just" ebooks I put up somewhere but classic books, not fund by myself.

Thank you

Comment: The term "technical writer" would be understood, but in English it refers to someone involved in the field of "technical writing."  It is very specific.  You should look up what it entails to make sure that it correctly describes your experience.  In English, too, we have different words for types of writer.  An author writes books.  A journalist writes for newspapers and magazines.  A columnist also writes for newspapers and magazines but in a different capacity.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Thanks. As for me, I have written books dedicated to C++ programming, artifical intelligence and similar topics. My books can be bought in bookstores across the country. What term would apply to me then? And the word "author" refers just to books? In the languages I know it always refer to the creator but it can be anything

Comment: Technical writers write instruction manuals and detailed step-by-step guides.  They write memoranda, white papers, usability reports, and other documentation. If this doesn't describe your writing, then you will be applying a misnomer calling yourself a technical writer.  If you write books about technology as a subject and not in a way that provides instructions, then I wouldn't call you a technical writer.  I'd call you an author of some sort, but I don't know what sort.

Comment: "I have written books dedicated to C++ programming, artifical intelligence and similar topics. My books can be bought in bookstores across the country."  That qualifies you as an "author".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refer to yourself as "Author of the following books:" and then list them by author (you and any co-authors), complete title (including subtitle, if any), year of publication, city of publication, name of publisher. You can include as much bibliographical information about the books as you like, including the ISBN, the number of pages, a description of the book's contents, and quotations of any positive reviews the books have received, whether in print, online, or in a personal letter or email to you.

If you have also written and published articles for journals and magazines, you can list them separately (e. g., "Author of the following articles and papers:" etc.). You can also list any unpublished papers you have written.

For a quick overview of the Modern Language Association's bibliographic guidelines (*which you do **not** have to follow exactly*, especially in a resume), Cornell University offers this information which might be helpful: https://www.library.cornell.edu/research/citation/mla